# Tcl/tk: How to bind keys to menu items directly instead of binding to events handlers

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How may I bind keys to menu items directly instead of binding to events handlers / procs.

That is instead of:

```
bind .t <space> {someProc}
```

How could it be done like:

```
bind .t <space> {direct menu action}
```

Comment: What is a `direct menu action`?   Example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the menu item is `.m` then you could do

```
bind .t <space> {.m invoke}
```

See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/menu.htm